# How to serve different index.html based on environment using Vite?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, plugins, frontend, vite

In webpack I used HtmlWebpackPlugin, which I could tell which HTML template I'd like to use. I wonder how can I achieve this same result using Vite.

The objective is to use React CDN in production (build), but I don't want to use it in development.

I had something like this in my webpack config:

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const common = require('./webpack.common')

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/template.dev.html'
    })
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [vite-plugin-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-html).

Based on the [docs](https://github.com/vbenjs/vite-plugin-html#usage) it supports to set the `template` file same way as **HtmlWebpackPlugin**.

Changing the template based on the `mode`, you'd need to use [conditional config](https://vitejs.dev/config/#conditional-config) in your "vite.config" file.

Edit:

As this plugin also allows to expose variables into the template, you might even not use two separate templates if the only difference is the `<script src="">`.

You might use something like: `<script src="<%- REACT_SCRIPT_SOURCE %>">`